# Why is the solution of this differential equation $Ln(1-z_1(z)/2)=K_1 z + K_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a lesson about mass transfer and diffusion and I have troubles to find the same solution given in the book.

> The differential equation is written as :
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{-cD_{12}\frac{\mathrm{d}z_1}{\mathrm{d}z}}{1-\frac{z_1}{2}}\right)}{\mathrm{d}z}=0$$

My reasonning :

$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{-cD_{12}\frac{\mathrm{d}z_1}{\mathrm{d}z}}{1-\frac{z_1}{2}}\right)}{\mathrm{d}z}=0 &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}z_1}{(1-z_1/2)\mathrm{d}z}\right)=0\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}z_1}{(1-z_1/2)}=K_1 \mathrm{d}z \\ &\Longleftrightarrow -2\log(z_1-2)=K_1z+K_2\end{align}$$

But I don't understand how to find $Ln(1-z_1/2)$..where I guess $Ln$ means $\log$. $z_1$ is a function of $z$. I know that $\log(1/x)=-\log(x)$ but ...

Can someone help me please? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is $z$ just the independent argument of $z_1$?

Comment: $z_1$ is the amount of the compound 1 at the distance z

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to check carefully the definition domain of $z_1$. In your last line, you assumed that you have $z_1 > 2$.

On the opposite, if you assume that $z_1 < 2$, then a correct primitive would be $-\displaystyle\frac 12 \log(2-z_1) = -\frac 12 (\log(2) + \log(1-z_1/2))$. Here, you find the desired $\log(1-z_1/2)$, I'll let you write the whole resolution.

You can find this primitive if you write $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}z_1}{1-z_1/2} = \frac 12\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}z_1}{2-z_1}$.

Comment: Here 0<z1<1. Thank you it will help me !

Answer (score 0):

On this step

$$\int \frac{d z_1}{1 - \frac{z_1}{2}} = \int K_1 dz$$

Let $u= 1 - \frac{z_1}{2}$, $-2 du = d z_1$. We get

$$-2 \ln u = K_1z + K_2$$
$$\ln (1 - \frac{z_1}{2}) = -\frac{K_1}{2} z - \frac{K_2}{2} $$

But $K_1, K_2$ are just arbitrary constants, so we can redefine them and get

$$\ln (1 - \frac{z_1}{2}) = K_1 z +K_2 $$